# Where are all these requests made by pods going to in a RKE2 kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, rancher

I'm using tcpdump in my nodes to track all requests/connections made from pods and I noticed there's a lot of entries going to addresses like the ones below. They clearly belong to something in the kubernetes cluster but there are no pods nor services with those addresses so I'm not sure what they mean. There are specially a lot of them made from the ingress nginx pods.

```
nginx.nginx-service:
ip-10-42-6-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.6.0), port 32734
ip-10-42-6-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.6.0), port 23633
ip-10-42-5-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.5.0), port 4478
ip-10-42-2-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.2.0), port 58426
ip-10-42-0-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.0.0), port 48799
ip-10-42-4-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.4.0), port 34161
ip-10-42-4-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.4.0), port 19961
ip-10-42-2-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.2.0), port 43050
ip-10-42-3-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.3.0), port 27502
ip-10-42-3-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.3.0), port 53304
ip-10-42-2-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.2.0), port 28669
ip-10-42-4-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.4.0), port 58908
ip-10-42-1-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.1.0), port 41605
ip-10-42-4-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.4.0), port 62816
ip-10-42-4-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.4.0), port 21103
ip-10-42-6-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.6.0), port 57593
ip-10-42-5-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.5.0), port 45286
ip-10-42-2-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.2.0), port 15532
ip-10-42-5-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.5.0), port 10268
ip-10-42-5-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.5.0), port 12798
ip-10-42-0-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.0.0), port 47151
ip-10-42-3-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.3.0), port 5760
ip-10-42-5-0.us-west-2.compute.internal (10.42.5.0), port 6432
```